# Caching and volatile memory when mmap /dev/mem

Tags: linux, caching, memory, linux-kernel, mmap

I have a hardware buffer that I have allocated in the kernel. This buffer receives DMA data from the PCIe bus. From Userspace I then map the hardware buffer into my virtual address space using `mmap /dev/mem`. My question is as follows:

1) How does `mmap` handling caching?

a) From reading about `mmap` I understand that when writing to the mapped region from userspace I may need to call msync to flush the cached version of memory into the 'file'. Since `/dev/mem` is implemented differently than an `mmaped` file, do I still need to `msync` my writes?

b) Since the memory I am mapping is `volatile` memory (DMA hardware writes to it), how do I maintain sync of my reads from this memory? If there are changes from the hardware in the physical memory, then I have written changes to my cache from userspace, then I `msync` my changes to flush my writes, are the physical memory changes lost due to me over writing with the flush?

c) When `mmaping /dev/mem` should I declare the returned pointer to virtual memory as `volatile`

I see a lot of documentation on `mmap` caching as it pertains to `mmaping` filesystem files (not volatile memory) but when it comes to `mmaping /dev/mem` I can't seem to get the same information (it could all be the same I guess).

Answer (score 0):

Open /dev/mem with O_SYNC for uncached access. I am having difficulty finding a authoritative source for that.